# MPAndroidChart -LineChart : How to make last draw point in the center of width

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart

How to make the last draw point in the middle of chart width?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. i am adding data in real time.

```
LineData plot = temperatureChart.getData();
temperatureChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(plot.getXMax() + 10f);
temperatureChart.moveViewToX(plot.getXMax() + 10f);

temperatureChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

if(temperatureChart.getVisibleXRange()!=20) {
    temperatureChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20f);
}
```